# How to force Tomcat (embedded in Spring Boot) to use standard java.util.logging instead of JULI?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat9

I'm running Tomcat as an embedded server inside of a Springboot app, so all the additional functionality in JULI such as multiple class loaders etc is not needed and just gets in the way.

I just want my app to use `java.util.logging` directly without the extra complication of JULI. I want a flat configuration where everything just flows directly to `java.util.logging` and the way I have configured it.

How can I ditch JULI?

**UPDATE**

The actual problem I'm having is that I'm unable to load a custom `Handler`... getting a `ClassNotFound`. I initially thought this was caused by JULI but really seems to be related to Spring Boot's System Class Manager unwillingness to load classes from `BOOT-INF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JULI is just a logging facade used by Tomcat for its internal logging (cf. [javadoc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/logging/package-summary.html)) based on [Apache Commons Logging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/). It is not a logging framework and does not perform any logging by itself.

By default it uses `java.util.logging` plain and simple the way you configured it.

The additional functionality you can find in a standalone Tomcat (per classloader configuration, multiple handlers of the same class, etc.) is provided by [`ClassLoaderLogManager`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/ClassLoaderLogManager.html). In order to use it you need to set:

```
-Djava.util.logging.logmanager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

as JVM parameter (anywhere else it will be probably ignored).

Tomcat's startup scripts add the above mentioned Java system property, but your Spring Boot application almost certainly does not. Hence your application is using `java.util.logging` plain and simple (unless you are using `spring-boot-starter-logging` in which case `java.util.logging` is redirected to LogBack).

**TL;DR**: by default Tomcat JULI simply forwards messages to `java.util.logging`. There are no complications.